# mysql where subquery with not in works, but subquery with in does not work

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

belHere is a MySql query that works just fine:

```
select PersonId
     , PersonState
     , PersonZip5
  from perslabel
 where PersonCountry = 'USA' 
   and concat(PersonState,PersonZip5) is not null
   and concat(PersonState,PersonZip5) Not In
         (select concat(Z3StateCode,Zip3Code) as statezip from Zip3)
```

There are five records in the table perslabel, two of them should be selected by this query, and that is exactly what happens.

Here is a MySql query that does not work:

```
 select PersonId, PersonState, PersonZip5 from perslabel
 where concat(PersonState,PersonZip5) IN
 (select concat(Z3StateCode,Zip3Code) as statezip from Zip3)
```

This query should return 3 records, but it returns none.

I can't think why changing "not in" to "in" should matter.  None of the concat combos are null, and adding that line to the second query makes no difference -- I still get 0 records.

I'm baffled about why the second query does not work.  Can anyone enlighten me?  Or tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I think we have to agree to disagree with the 'works just fine' idea. If it works at all, it's an absolute performance killer, and antithetical to principle of normalisation.

Comment: `where (PersonState,PersonZip5) IN (select Z3StateCode, Zip3Code from Zip3)` is enough - both concat() and alias are excess. And this form avoids concat('A','AB') = concat('AA','B').

Comment: `and concat(PersonState,PersonZip5) is not null` Use separate checks: `and PersonState is not null and PersonZip5 is not null`, function in WHERE decreases the performance, sometimes dramatically.

Comment: @Akina, glad to learn this -- always happy to avoid concat.

Comment: @Strawberry -- 'works just find in the context that it produces the desired result.  May be a performance killer, but I expect only hundreds of records at most, so that may not matter.  If you can offer an alternative way to accomplish this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Nic3500 -- As far as I can tell my example is about as minimal as it can get. It has certainly generated the error many times from my very minimal table perslabel.  If you cannot get an error from the bad code, please le me know.  The difference between what you have done and what I have done might be a clue about what's wrong here.

Comment: It's certainly minimal.

Comment: Hey guys, I found the error, and it was not in the code.  I was concatenating the wrong thing.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Yes it is minimal, but there is no table description, sample data, ...  I am missing something.

Comment: @Nic3500  Maybe I am missing something.  Next time I'll include a table and some data.